# How to get the binary data from a download link

Tags: c#, objective-c, binary, download

I need to get the binary data of a download link.

When I run this link in the browser it always starts download manager.  Rather I would like to copy that binary and display it on teh browser. How is this possible in any language.

Objective c or c#  preferred.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, display the binary on the browser or download it using a program, then display it in the browser or something else again?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) class you could perform an HTTP request to a given url and retrieve the result:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] data = client.DownloadData("http://example.com/foo");
    // Do something with the binary data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to download?  For example, to display a PDF directly to the browser you can do something like this:

```
var data = HoweverYouAreLoadingYourByteArray();
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyFile.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(data);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

Just make sure you are setting the correct content type for whatever type of binary file you are trying to push to the browser.